# VPN Issues While Using Phone's Hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

When I'm out in the field working, I use my phone's built in Wifi Hot Spot to gain internet access.  For some reason, it won't allow me to VPN into my companies network while using my phone's Hot Spot.

Is there certain features I need to activate or deactivate to get my computer's VPN to work while connected to my cell phone's hot spot?

Using a Google Pixel XL and iPhone 6 along with Dell Laptop.

Answer (score 4):

Solved me, I had to change APN setting from IPv6 to IPv4.

Comment: This looks like you’re saying “Thank you” because somebody else answered your question, but I don’t see what answer you might be referring to.  If you are saying “Thank you”, please don’t — the answer box is meant only for answers.  But, if you have discovered a solution, please [edit] your post to present your solution *as* an answer, with enough context and detail to allow somebody else to understand it and use it.

Comment: This is a bit of a technical exercise, but you can do it by [creating a new APN](https://www.androidcentral.com/what-apn-and-how-do-i-change-it) and making sure it's set to IPv4. APN settings will vary between phones and providers but I found mine for EE, with a Huawei P20 Pro [here](https://apn-uk.gishan.net/en/apn/ee/huawei-p20-pro)

Comment: This worked for me, on a Samsung Galaxy S20+. Go to settings -> Connections -> Mobile Networks -> Access Point Names and select the service you're connected to. Select "APN protocol" and set to IPV4. You may want to set the same for "APN roaming protocol" too.

Answer (score 2):

It may be due to complications with the IP address assigned by your cell phone network.  If possible, go to Settings, Cellular Networks, Preferred network type, and set it to 3G.  Then try the VPN again.

Answer (score 1):

Solved for me connecting VPN by changing 4g to 3g in mobile networks, 
after connecting I switched back to 4g and still my work VPN is connected and working

Comment: Today this helped me to resolve the same issue on Samsung Galaxy A52.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Pixel 6 Pro and had the same problem when connecting to a VPN a laptop connected to the phone's hotspot. I tried all suggestion but nothing worked. At last I tried to modify the APN type to "default,supl" instead of "default,supl,dun" and it works like a charm!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in the Setting of your android phone click on access point > go to General > apn protocol and apn roaming protocol set it to ipv4
this did the job for Poco M2 Pro

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing this issue.
Fixed it myself by following below steps.

- Go to phone settings
- Mobile network
- Select SIM
- Disable it and enable again.

Issue fixed :).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).